# Why am I getting Keras shape mismatch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following a Keras mnist example for beginners. I have tried to change the labels to suit my own data which has 3 distinct text classifications. I am using "to_categorical" to achieve this. The shape looks right to me, but "fit" gets an error:

```
train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=3)

print(train_images.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
```

> (7074, 28, 28)
>
> (7074, 3)
>
> Blockquote
>   Blockquote
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/lawrence/PycharmProjects/tester2019/KeraTest.py", line 131,
>   in 
>       model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)   File "C:\Users\lawrence\PycharmProjects\tester2019\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1536, in fit
>       validation_split=validation_split)   File "C:\Users\lawrence\PycharmProjects\tester2019\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 992, in _standardize_user_data
>       class_weight, batch_size)   File "C:\Users\lawrence\PycharmProjects\tester2019\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1154, in _standardize_weights
>       exception_prefix='target')   File "C:\Users\lawrence\PycharmProjects\tester2019\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 332, in standardize_input_data
>       ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got
>   array with shape (3,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss since your labels are one hot encoded.

Alternatively, you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` if you do not one hot encode the labels. In that case, the labels should have shape `(batch_size, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I am new to deep learning, but I read one-hot is important if labels are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the loss,

```
loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
```

when the target label contain multiple instances.